# np.arange followed by reshape

Tags: python, numpy

What is a more Pythonic way of doing this?

```
min_odds = np.arange( 1.05, 2.0, 0.01 )
min_odds = min_odds.reshape( len( min_ods ), -1 )
```

The code creates an ndarray of shape (95,) and converts it to shape (95,1).

Also, why does numpy sometimes create arrays of size (95,) with a blank last dimension?

Comment: `(95,)` is the shape of a 1d array (think 'vector').  `(95,1)` is the shape of a 2d array.  `(1,95)` is another 2d shape.  `arange` creates a 1d.

Comment: I loved how you've phrased the question: 'Pythonic' - lol!

Answer (score 11):

I often follow `arange` with a `reshape` to generate test arrays, e.g.

```
 np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
```

Use `-1` to avoid taking `len()`, e.g.

```
 np.arange(10).reshape(-1,1).shape # (10, 1)
```

`arange` always returns a 1d array.  `numpy` arrays can have any number of dimensions, including 0.  Shape is expressed as a tuple.  `(10,)` is just a 1 term tuple.  (the , is needed to distinguish it from `(10)`).

Answer (score 4):

You can slice with `np.newaxis` (which is just an fancy alias for `None`) if you'd like:

```
>>> np.arange( 1.05, 2.0, 0.01 )[:,np.newaxis].shape
(95, 1)
```

If you prefer what you've got, I'd get rid of the `-1` and just use `1` (unless you want your users to have to look up what the `-1` is supposed to mean like I just did...).

```
>>> arr = np.arange( 1.05, 2.0, 0.01 )
>>> arr = arr.reshape(len(arr), 1)
>>> arr.shape
(95, 1)
```

As for your second question,

> "why does numpy sometimes create arrays of size (95,) with a blank last dimension?"

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking.  `ndarray.shape` *is* a `tuple`.  A tuple with a single element's string representation looks like `(something,)`.

<sup>Also note the comments below about preferring `np.linspace` to `np.arange` in this case.</sup>

Comment: Nah, no copy involved, just a view into the same array. Also, you are not supposed to sue `np.arange` with floating point arguments, as it often backfires due to rounding errors and gives you one extra argument. In this case, `np.linspace(1.05, 1.99, 95)[:, None]` would be the preferred option.

Comment: @Jaime -- Good point about `np.linspace`... I wasn't thinking about that part of the code :-).